# if avg age > 61 then status value is ok else not ok in HIve

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
1,ram,45,IT,50000
2,raj,30,IT,45000
3,ram,45,IT,50000
4,raj,60,PM,25000
5,raj,65,PM,35000
Output
IT,40,Not ok
BPO,62.5,ok
```

need to get the output in above order in Hive

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You haven't given us much to go on, or showed us what you've tried so far.  Here's a link on [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hql

```
    SELECT a.dept,
           age,
           CASE
             WHEN a.age > 61 THEN 'OK'
             ELSE 'Not Ok'
           END AS age
    FROM   (SELECT dept,
                   Avg(age) age
            FROM   avgq
            GROUP  BY dept) a;
```